# Is it possible to determine whether a method is synchronous or asynchronous?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

Suppose I'm using a library which I don't have access to its source code, and it has one of the following methods: *I will just call them type A, B, and C*.

**Type A:**

```
public async Task FakeAsyncMethod1()
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        // Some synchronous CPU-bound work.
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    });
}
```

**Type B:**

```
public async Task<string> FakeAsyncMethod2()
{
    string result = await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        // Some synchronous IO-bound work.
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("someURL");
        using (var stream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            return reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

**Type C:**

```
public async Task<string> RealAsyncMethod()
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    // Some asynchronous IO-bound work.
    var responseMsg = await client.GetAsync("someURL");
    return await responseMsg.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Now, I'm not expecting to be able to differentiate between type-A and type-B. They both wrap some synchronous work in a `Task.Run`, and I believe it doesn't matter whether it's CPU-bound or IO-bound.

**So, my question is:**

Since it would be a very bad implementation if the developer of the library used type-A or type-B, **is there a way to tell whether a method is of type-C (fully asynchronous) or not?**

**Additionally**, suppose we have a method similar to type-B (or A), but the blocking code isn't even wrapped in a `Task.Run`, is there a way to determine that it is a blocking method (blocks the current thread)? Of course, I can *manually* check if it blocks the UI thread (e.g., in a WinForms app), but I was wondering if there's a better way to do that (perhaps, ***programmatically***).

---

**Edit:** I'm not looking for a solution that involves analyzing the code (e.g., one could suggest using a decompiler, etc.). Sometimes the source code is even available but I wouldn't check it for one reason or another.

What I'm looking for is a way to figure that out directly by running the code and analyzing its behavior (e.g., analyze the threads, etc., *I'm not sure how*), and I was wondering if that's possible.

Comment: Hi, how are methods A and B synchronous? I understood await keyword in a sense that it yields the control to the caller if the awaited Task is not finished yet.

Comment: @LubošHemala that's right, but the code in the method body (inside `Task.Run`) is synchronous. Read [Stephen Cleary's article "Task.Run Etiquette"](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/taskrun-etiquette-and-proper-usage.html) for more.

Comment: You would have analyze the IL.

Comment: @glenebob Not really. Roslyn has a huge API for code analysis

Comment: What if the implementation behind client.GetAsync() is also just something like Task.Run wrapper around synchronous code? (i am more speaking conceptually, i am not making any particular claims about the HttpClient implementation) In other words, if a RealAsyncMethod is awaiting a FakeAsyncMethod, is it then still a RealAsyncMethod?

Comment: @glenebob I edited the question. CamiloTerevinto, can it be used for such thing? I never used it before.

Comment: Yes, you can analyze a lot of stuff. It would take some time to implement though, but I'd guess it would have value in every future project

Comment: @elgonzo, nope, it would still be a FakeAsyncMethod. My understanding is that a RealAsyncMethod never executes synchronous code (code that would block the current thread, or start another thread and block it for some time), which is something `HttpClient.GetAsync()` method does not do, AFAIK.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto thanks, I'll look into it.

Comment: To whoever voted to close this question, out of curiosity, can you be kind enough to explain how it is too broad? I'm asking about a very specific problem with a clear example, so I'm having a hard time understanding how it's too broad!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure of what i state below but even if wrong or incomplete could be a good starting point.

Since Method A and Method B block a thread of the thread pool (while a full asyncronous method does not), as long as you control the threads created by your process you could compare the available thread in the thread pool in different time T1 T2.

I created a simple example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var t = MainAsync(args);

    t.Wait();

    Console.ReadKey();
}

static async Task MainAsync(string[] args)
{
    int availableThreadT1;
    int availableAsyncIOThreadT1;

    int availableThreadT2;
    int availableAsyncIOThreadT2;          

    ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads(out availableThreadT1, out availableAsyncIOThreadT1);

    //var t1 = FakeAsync(); //Locked thread 1
    var t2 = RealAsync(); //Locked thread 0

    ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads(out availableThreadT2, out availableAsyncIOThreadT2);

    //Console.Write($"Locked threads from FakeAsync {availableThreadT1 - availableThreadT2} \r\n");
    Console.Write($"Locked threads from RealAsync {availableThreadT1 - availableThreadT2} \r\n");
}

static async Task FakeAsync()
{

    var t = Task.Run(() => 
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    });


    await t;

}

static async Task RealAsync()
{

    var t = Task.Delay(1000);

    await t;

}
```

Comment: But you could never be sure if the change was caused by that method call.  It could be caused by some other thread queueing/finishing work, or the thread pool deciding to add/remove threads at that point in time.  Additionally a method doing the async over sync antipattern might be using a non-thread pool thread.

Comment: Yeah that what i meant with 'as long as you control the threads created by your process'

Comment: It's a good start but I think the main problem is that a non-thread pool thread could be used as Servy suggested (I used `Task.Run` just as an example).

Comment: @Servy Assuming only thread pool threads are used, and I used an *empty* project for testing (something like Giovanni's example above), could it still produce an inaccurate result?

Comment: @GiovanniRomio But you never can.  You don't control the thread pool.  By design it will spin up and tear down threads based on its own heuristics of what it thinks will perform best.